# Best practice for use of session and request attributes in servlet and JSP for MVC compliance

Tags: jsp, session, servlets, request

I have a scenario where a servlet is required to display details of a person on a page, but I want to also store the details of the person in the session, so is this code viable:

```
Person person = // Populated elsewhere.   
session.setAttribute("person", person); // Store Person in session.
request.setAttribute("person", person); // Store Person in request.
// Set URL for JSP.
```

I ask because the session object can be accessed by the JSP. Or is it better to populate the JSP only using the request because this is more MVC compliant?

Comment: Try to use lowest scope to avoid memory consumption. scope from lowest to higher. `page -> request -> session -> application`

Comment: Given that this is only a demo application with minuscule amounts of data, I would normally follow this but I think that storing my person in the session and allowing the JSPs to access it should be alright in this case. But I will say that under other circumstances, session-based storage should be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your code.
If you need to store that information permanently within the session, store it in session. So all JSPs can access this data.

If you need to store that information but only for request purposes (such as Forms), store it in request. So only the JSP to which you forward the request can read the data.

Comment: That is the approach I have taken. But I wonder if it is best for JSPs to access the session.

Comment: If Person contains some data of a logged user and you want to store these data for managing some other JSPs and not only the forwarded one, that may be the page that confirms the correctness of the login that may say "Hi Morgan you're 30 years old today" it's the case in which you should use session scope. If you need these data only for the forwarded page you are in the request scope case.

The MVC model is not an issue, you've manipulated the data in servlet part of the project and you show the data in JSPs, so more or less you're "compliant" (broadly speaking).

Comment: This is only a demo application but when a person enters their ID, the session stores the details retrieved from the database in the session because other pages rely on the person's id. There is little point in forwarding the id as part of the request for other pages, and then retrieving it in the next servlet as a parameter.

Comment: If you are concerned about memory consumption, you could pass only the ID in session-scope. You have a sort of trade-off between memory consumption and """computational complexity""". If you create a session Beam with all the useful information about an User you may have a sort of overhead in memory but you don't need to query the DB in other servlets to provide beam to the other JSPs. Otherwise you preserve memory, but you've to re-query the DB to extract all the info that the corresponding JSP needs. This is the situation if I've understood your "architecture".

Comment: I think you do understand my scenario. Given that this is only a demo application with minuscule amounts of data, session storage of the person object is fine. Setting the id to session is another option but yes, it would require DB calls in other servlets. Of course where a request updates the person, the session object will be updated.